# Java Dynamic number thread Creation and Mangement

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create dynamic number of thread which is depends on the database Number of database rows..

```
List list = session.createQuery("From Devices").list();
```

Number of thread is depends on the `list.size()`.
I am Creating dynamic number of thread using For loop

```
new Thread(){public void run(){/* Task of each thread */}.start();
```

Is it right way to create dynamic number of thread ?? If i use shared variable do I need to define synchronized.. Any another idea how to manage thread where thread count become dynamic and depends on User.

Another question how can i define some private variable which is separated to each thread and not sheared to each other ..????

thanks

Comment: Take a look at the Executors class, particularly the method to create a [fixed thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a team of threads to execute something on every row I would instead use a thread pool:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(list.size());
```

It's much easier to submit work and manage the pool than using an array of threads.

After this, synchronization depends on the actual computation. If you are concurrently modifying some shared state (list, counter) you will need to synchronize access across threads.

Finally, to define a thread task with private state:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

     private int state; // example of private state

     public ThreadTask(int state) {
        this.state = state;
     }

     public void run() {
        // task code
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it right way to create dynamic number of thread ??

Yes, but not very elegant. Consider creating a separate class:

```
public class DeviceHandler implements Runnable {
  //...
}
```

and then:

```
List<Device> list = session.createQuery("From Devices").list();

for(Device device: list) {
  Thread thread = new Thread(new DeviceHandler(device));
  thread.start();
}
```

Note that I assume each thread is responsible for a device so I am eagerly passing `Device` instance to each thread. You'll need it, trust me.

> If i use shared variable do I need to define synchronized..

If multiple threads are accessing the same variable, you have to use some sort of synchronization: `synchronized`, `Lock`, `volatile`, `Atomic*`... This is way too broad for this question.

> Any another idea how to manage thread where thread count become dynamic and depends on User.

Not sure what you mean. The thread count *is* dynamic in your current solution.

> Another question how can i define some private variable which is separated to each thread and not sheared to each other ..????

Well, in Java you actually can't have variables local to thread (escept obscure `ThreadLocal`) because everything lives on global heap. However if you encapsulate some variable and let only a single thread to access it, you'll be safe:

```
public class DeviceHandler implements Runnable {
  private int noGettersAndSettersForMe;
}
```